# Onscreen input with the keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I guess my problem's going to be much clear if I present it in image :

http://i41.servimg.com/u/f41/15/91/45/84/keyboa10.png

Image 2 and 3 is what's happening when I click on one of the edittext fields and image 4 is what I would like (to have the keyboard under all the fields...).

These images are just an example, this isn't my app :p ... I already tried stuff like

```
    <activity name="EditContactActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
    ...
    </activity>
```

but the result is never IMG4 :S

Does anyone have a clue on how to get to IMG4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Scroll View for your xml-file. It's can solved your problem.